# Value is still not setting to an integer?

Tags: php

I have a simple script that will dynamically convert minutes into minutes, hours and days dynamically( Meaning if I have 1 minute, the script will put put "1 Minute", and if I have 61 mins, the script will say "1 Hour and 1 Minute" etc. with the proper grammar). Basically, although I try to set the value of a variable as an int, my current time (112 mins) comes out as: 1.8666666666667 Hours and 52 Minutes.

```
settype($otime, "integer");
settype($hours, "integer");
settype($mins, "integer");
settype($hour, "integer");
if($otime == 1) {
  $otime = "1 Minute";
}else if($otime < 60 && $otime !=1) {
  $otime = $otime." Minutes";
}
else if($otime >= 60 && $otime < 1440) {
  $hours = $otime / 60;
  $mins = $otime % 60;
  if($mins == 1 && $hours != 1) {
    $otime = $hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  else if($mins != 1 && $hours == 1) {
    $otime = $hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
  else if($mins == 1 && $hours == 1) {
    $otime = $hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  else {
    $otime = $hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
}
else if($otime >= 1440) {
  $days = $otime / 1440;
  $hour = $otime % 1440;
  $hours = $hour / 60;
  $mins = $hour % 60;
  if($days == 1 && $hours != 1 && $mins != 1) {
    $otime = $days." Day ".$hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
  if($days != 1 && $hours == 1 && $mins != 1) {
    $otime = $days." Days ".$hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
  if($days != 1 && $hours != 1 && $mins == 1) {
    $otime = $days." Days ".$hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  if($days == 1 && $hours == 1 && $mins != 1) {
    $otime = $days." Day ".$hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
  if($days == 1 && $hours == 1 && $mins == 1) {
    $otime = $days." Day ".$hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  if($days != 1 && $hours == 1 && $mins == 1) {
    $otime = $days." Days ".$hours." Hour and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  if($days == 1 && $hours != 1 && $mins == 1) {
    $otime = $days." Day ".$hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minute";
  }
  if($days != 1 && $hours != 1 && $mins != 1) {
    $otime = $days." Days ".$hours." Hours and ".$mins." Minutes";
  }
}
```

Also - Is there a simpler way to do this? and did I miss any if's (For grammar purposes)

Comment: http://us2.php.net/DateTime

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel.  Use the PHP Date/Time functions to accomplish rather than trying to calculate it yourself.: http://us2.php.net/DateTime

Comment: @Luke Peterson: how would you do that with `DateTime`?

Comment: @Cfreak I've looked into it and I don't think it has the ability to output the time exactly as I wanted it in the OP, along with the correct grammar. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Fixed this by setting the type of variable after performing the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much simpler way of doing this without so many if statements but also providing the correct plural language.

```
echo minutes2human(1211);

function minutes2human($mins) {
  $m = floor($mins % 60);
  $h = floor(($mins % 1440) / 60);
  $d = floor($mins / 1440);

  $m_word = ($m == 1 ? 'Minute' : 'Minutes');
  $h_word = ($h == 1 ? 'Hour'   : 'Hours');
  $d_word = ($d == 1 ? 'Day'    : 'Days');

  return "$d $d_word $h $h_word and $m $m_word";
}
```

We reduce a lot of your if statements by checking if minutes are 1, hours are 1, and if days are 1, then just combining them all into one string. As opposed to checking each possible case (if minutes are 1 and hours are not 1 and days are not 1, if minutes are 1, hours are 1, and days are not 1) etc...

Comment: You might have messed up on there somewhere - because it may just be me or it's converting 60 minutes into 0 Days 0 Hours and 1 Minute. Thanks though :) Also - Is it possible to remove the Minutes/Hours/Days if it is equal to 0?

Comment: @user3875455 Check again - it's what I get for trying to only type in the code box and not test my work. =P Anyways, it would be very easy to do that, just check $m, $h and $d if they equal 0 don't add them to our return string.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", ($minutes * 60));
```

Or with a function [DateTime()](https://www.php.net/DateTime) :(Thanks to @Ryan Kempt)

```
    function minutesToTime($minutes) {
    $minutes = $minutes * 60;
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$minutes");
    if($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i') !=0 ){
        $min = ($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i') == 1 ? '  %i Minute' : '  %i Minutes');
    } 
     else{
        $min = '';
     }
     if($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h') !=0 ){
        $hours = ($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h') == 1 ? ' %h Hour' : ' %h Hours');
    } 
     else{
        $hours = '';
     }
     if($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a') !=0 ){
        $days = ($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a') == 1 ? ' %a Day' : ' %a Days');
    } 
     else{
        $days = '';
     }
     if($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%s') !=0 ){
        $seconds = ($dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%s') == 1 ? ' %s Second' : ' %s Seconds');
    } 
     else{
        $seconds = '';
     }

    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format($days.' '.$hours.' '.$min.'  '.$seconds.'');
}


echo minutesToTime(456543.5);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 1317 Days, 1 Hour, 3 Minutes and 30 Seconds
```

Comment: It's generally not a semantically correct code, since interval != date. Not to mention that it will return **incorrect** results with intervals more than 24 hours. You also don't take into account effect DST will bring.

Comment: Will this say 1 minutes or 1 minute? Also - If the time is 60 - does it say 1 Hour - or 1 Hours 0 Minutes etc.

Comment: if it's 60 it will output : `0 days, 1 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting the type for the variables before than the variables have value.

For the $hours, set the type after the division. Replace the line

```
$hours = $otime / 60;
```

for:

```
$hours = $otime / 60;
settype($hours, "integer");
```

It's probably that you will need to do this with the other variables $mins and $hour

Comment: I check your code with a simple proof of concept and, with this modifications, it works